# How to test IAP (in-app purchase) in iOS Simulator OR on the Device?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, in-app-purchase

I've implemented a simple non-consumable in-app purchase mechanism by following the Ray Wenderlich tutorial book.

When my app starts, I initiate a product info request:

```
self.productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];
_productsRequest.delegate = self;
[_productsRequest start];
```

The SKProductRequest gets created. It has a memory address but nothing else happens. None of the delegate methods gets called:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"Product info received...");
    NSArray *products = response.products;
    for (SKProduct *product in products) {
        NSLog(@"ID: %@, title:%@, (%f)", product.productIdentifier, product.localizedTitle, product.price.floatValue);
    }

    self.productsRequest = nil;
}

- (void)request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Failed to load list of products");
    self.productsRequest = nil;
}
```

I checked twice:

- App fully set-up in iTunes Connect.
- Status of app in ITC is "Prepare for Upload"
- One non-consumable IAP added.
- Status of IAP product in ITC is "Ready to Submit"
- App ID is com.mycompany.myapp both for the app and in the plist. Checked twice.
- IAP uses com.mycompany.myapp.productname (using exact same ID for the request).
- Created a test user account in ITC.
- Nothing submitted to Apple yet.
- My Mac has internet access.
- There are no other messages in the console or on screen.

The Ray Wenderlich book doesn't mention I must do anything else besides this.

Only *once* I saw a -didFailWithError: call to my delegate on the Device, but it never again appeared. My delegate doesn't get called both on device or simulator. I let it run for minutes with no response at all.

iTunes Connect gives this confusing warning:

> Your first In-App Purchase(s) must be submitted with a new app
>   version. Select them from the In-App Purchases section of the Version
>   Details page and then click Ready to Upload Binary.

Is this required prior to being able to test In-App Purchases?

Comment: With Xcode 5.1, IAP testing works fine in the simulator.

Answer (score 29):

In the current version of Xcode 5.0 (5A1413), In-App purchases will not work in the iOS simulator.

> StoreKit (In-App purchases) will not work in the Simulator. 13962338

Source: Xcode 5.0 Release Notes > Known issues > iOS Simulator https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/xc5_release_notes/xc5_release_notes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH2-SW303

Comment: You can test StoreKit in the simulator in Xcode 5.1+.

Answer (score 21):

In iOS simulator documentation it is written :

> API Limitations
>
> Within iOS Simulator, there are some limitations to the APIs and
>   features, including:
>
> ```
> Apple Push Services
> Privacy alerts for access to Photos, Contacts, Calendar, and Reminders
> The UIBackgroundModes key
> iCloud document syncing and key-value storage support
> ```
>
> Unsupported frameworks include:
>
> ```
> External Accessory
> Media Player
> Message UI 
> Event Kit
> In UIKit, the UIVideoEditorController class
> Store Kit
> ```

As in-app purchase needs Store Kit to work and the Store Kit framework is unsupported for Simulator, you can't test IAP in iOS Simulator.

More information : [iOS Simulator documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH4-SW1)

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/DevelopingwithStoreKit/DevelopingwithStoreKit.html states:

"Store Kit *can* be tested in the iOS Simulator, except for hosted content downloads."

Comment: As of writing this comment, "Store Kit" is *not* mentioned anymore in the list of unsupported frameworks in iOS Simulator.

Comment: @rpitting - yes but IAP is still not working. I am convinced that there are two Apples: one that creates amazing hardware and software for the masses and another Apple controlled by Darth Vader that hates developers and create crappy stuff like Xcode.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately there are several things you can not test on the simulator. In App Purchases belongs in that list.

So you can not test In App Purchases in simulator, you need an iOS device for that.

**Edit:** As far as I can see, that is what happens when you try to test IAP on the simulator, purchase delegates won't get called.

Comment: Editing my question now as I don't get any delegate calls on the device either.

Answer (score 7):

UPDATE OF 2020 YEAR: **You can now test in-app purchases in Xcode**

Important notice:

> Testing StoreKit in iOS, watchOS, or tvOS apps requires Xcode 12 or
> later running on macOS 10.15 or later. Testing StoreKit in a macOS app
> requires Xcode 12 or later running on macOS 11 or later.

Apple [tutorial here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/testing_in-app_purchases_in_xcode)

Comment: Can use use this method for `react-native-iap` and iaphub ?

Answer (score 2):

You can test in-app purchases in Xcode 12 from Apple documentation

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/testing_in-app_purchases_in_xcode?language=objc

And custom manual

https://www.appcoda.com/storekit-testing/

Comment: This is not an acceptable answer. please read https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118582/what-is-an-acceptable-answer

Answer (score 1):

I figured out something:

I initiated the SKProductRequest *immediately* at the end of AppDelegate's -didFinishLaunching... and it never worked.

Then I made a delayed call and waited 3 seconds. From then on it started working.
So you can't make StoreKit requests immediately after app launch.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your skProductRequest object is declared?
Try a global declaration of skProductRequest.