# SKStoreProductViewController display apps from developer

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

i'm using `SKStoreProductViewController` to implement "more apps" functionality, but when I tap on a product on the list, i'm getting only blank screen, there is also a warning in console:

> Could not request view controller: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain error 2.)"

this happens only on ios 7, in ios 6 it simply redirects to app store, here is my code:

```
SKStoreProductViewController *productVC = [[SKStoreProductViewController alloc] init];
productVC.delegate = self;
NSDictionary *productParameters = @{ SKStoreProductParameterITunesItemIdentifier :  <itunes developer ID>};
[productVC loadProductWithParameters:productParameters completionBlock:^(BOOL result, NSError *error) {
    if(error)
    {
       [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:[error localizedDescription]
                                                            message:nil
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];


    }

    if (result )
    {
        [self presentViewController:productVC animated:NO completion:nil];
    }

}];
```

i think this is ios 7 bug, any help greatly appricated

Comment: Appears to be working on iOS8! :)

Comment: Working perfectly. Can someone please tell where I can find <itunes developer ID> in iTunesConnect or developer.apple.com? I have got it by copying link from itunes, which is valid only if one or more apps are submitted on AppStore. What if I am going to my first app, then how can I get <itunes developer ID> ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in iOS 7. See https://devforums.apple.com/message/951745 (requires Apple dev login) where an Apple employee confirms that "The SKSPVC does not support this currently.  It currently only supports showing an individual product."

Pretty annoying, since this used to work great and was a great way for a company to show users its other apps. Back to the drawing board!

Comment: This whole problem was driving me slightly mad, so I created a new component that presents a list of products (you provide them yourself, rather than showing all products for a given company) and when the user taps one, SKSPVC is used to display it: https://github.com/thoughtbot/MultiProductViewer

Answer (score -1):

If you are using simulator, Inapp purchases (storekit) will not work in ios7 but only ios6.

Check here - [How to test IAP (in-app purchase) in iOS Simulator OR on the Device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040491/how-to-test-iap-in-app-purchase-in-ios-simulator-or-on-the-device)