# Show App Store apps, not iTunes music, by given developer with same link for all OS versions?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

A link of this format, https://itunes.apple.com/artist/ARTIST-NAME/idNUM, takes users to the App Store and shows all apps by ARTIST-NAME for iPhone 5S users running iOS 8.

However, the same link on a iPhone 6 running iOS 9 shows music options in iTunes.

What's the right link format for all OS versions that will show apps by a given developer?

The link needs to be shared via SMS and listed on a web page.

Comment: Use `SKStoreProductViewController` - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20675880/skstoreproductviewcontroller-display-apps-from-developer?s=1|1.4845 Works with iOS 8.0 and later.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks! (1) what don't you know? :) (2) how come you didn't post as an answer? (3) so there isn't a link format you could use on a web page?

Comment: I didn't post an answer because I don't know what link to use. I use `SKStoreProductViewController`. It's a better experience for the user since they don't leave your app.

Answer (score 2):

The URL:

```
http://itunes.com/apps/COMPANY-NAME
```

entered into Safari on an iOS device running iOS 9 prompts the user if they wish to open the URL in iTunes Store. Choosing to do so launches the iTunes Store app to a page showing all of the apps of the developer.

Apple used to support the "appstore.com" domain and such links are discussed at [Technical Q&A QA1633](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1633/_index.html) but such links don't work any more under iOS 9. However, that document discusses rules to apply to the "COMPANY-NAME" to make the above URL work as needed.

- Remove all whitespace
- Convert all characters to lower-case
- Remove all copyright (©), trademark (™) and registered mark (®) symbols
- Replace ampersands ("&") with "and"
- Remove most punctuation (See Listing 2 for the set)
- Replace accented and other "decorated" characters (ü, å, etc.) with their elemental character (u, a, etc.)
- Leave all other characters as-is.

Comment: Upvoted. Thanks again @rmaddy. Unfortunately, the link doesn't appear to work for iOS 8, still haven't tested on iOS 9.

Comment: I tested under iOS 9 before posting so I know it works there. I don't have an my devices with iOS 8. I'll keep digging.

Comment: If I use http://itunes.com/apps/apple it opens the iTunes app (not the App Store) and enters ( " apple " ) into the search field. 

http://appstore.com/apple works fine for me. (As do a couple of other developers)

(iOS 9.3.2, also not possible to test iOS 8, but http://appstore.com/apple worked for us back then)

@Crashalot: Big question: Where do you open the link? On a "real" website or within a WebView? itms-apps:// does works very well in a WebView

Comment: @Oddie opened both within a website and launched from within the app itself ... rmaddy, did you find something that worked on iOS 8? thanks both!

Comment: @rmaddy which version of iOS 9 did you test on? one of our iOS 9 users said `http://itunes.com/apps/COMPANY-NAME` opens the iTunes app not the App Store app.