# In-App Purchase: No pop-up prompt when clicked

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, ios-simulator

So when I click on an in-app purchase that I installed in my game in xcode simulator, nothing pops up and I keep getting this error message in Xcode:

"Cocos2d: In-App Purchases : buy_product - product com.divided.removeads is NOT confirmed by application store. Check you store account and initialization code."

I checked everything in iTunes Connect and everything is setup correctly (submitted in-app purchase, same com.divided.removeads id that is in code, etc.)

What could be the problem?  Any help would be ever so greatly appreciated! :-)

Comment: Is that *exactly* what the error says?

Comment: you have tried it on a device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use IAP with simulator :

> StoreKit (In-App purchases) will not work in the Simulator. 13962338

Source: Xcode 5.0 Release Notes > Known issues > iOS Simulator https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-SW241

CF this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19126196/315374