# Crash report for iOS App

Tags: ios, crash, in-app-purchase, mkstorekit

I am having problem with my in-app purchase section in my app. The problem is only on iPhone 6, 6s and iPad Air. The app is crashing when tapping any in-app purchase.

This is the crash report:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 18446744073709551615 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b86ef65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010b241deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b752a94 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 212
    3   Chubby Vikings Free                 0x0000000106654366 -[MKStoreManager addToQueue:] + 294
    4   Chubby Vikings Free                 0x0000000106653fde __52-[MKStoreManager buyFeature:onComplete:onCancelled:]_block_invoke + 526
    5   Chubby Vikings Free                 0x00000001065ac2ae +[MKSKProduct verifyProductForReviewAccess:onComplete:onError:] + 174
    6   Chubby Vikings Free                 0x0000000106653d46 -[MKStoreManager buyFeature:onComplete:onCancelled:] + 502
    7   Chubby Vikings Free                 0x00000001065d5a79 -[DBPurchaseManager makePurchase:onComplete:onCancel:] + 313
    8   Chubby Vikings Free                 0x00000001065e1fd1 -[vShopCoinsPopup clickCoinsPack1:] + 225
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b75d85c __invoking___ + 140
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b75d6ae -[NSInvocation invoke] + 286
    11  Chubby Vikings Free                 0x00000001066a0773 -[CCMenuItem activate] + 67
    12  Chubby Vikings Free                 0x000000010669d80e -[CCMenu ccTouchEnded:withEvent:] + 286
    13  Chubby Vikings Free                 0x00000001066edfae -[CCTouchDispatcher touches:withEvent:withTouchType:] + 1598
    14  Chubby Vikings Free                 0x00000001066eea3e -[CCTouchDispatcher touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 78
    15  Chubby Vikings Free                 0x0000000106670a64 -[CCTouchView touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 84
    16  UIKit                               0x0000000108b67aa3 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000108b68691 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
    18  UIKit                               0x0000000108b1a752 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000108af5fcc _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6693
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b79b0a1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b790fcc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b790483 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010b78fe98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010dabbad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    25  UIKit                               0x0000000108afb676 UIApplicationMain + 171
    26  Chubby Vikings Free                 0x00000001065977c4 main + 100
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010bd5292d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: check your product list array, it will return empty list

Comment: Show the implementation of `[vShopCoinsPopup clickCoinsPack1:]`.

Comment: @NANNAV Thank you. Can you please provide me with more help. I am not sure how to check product list array. thanks

Comment: @ThomasVarberg add your code to reference, else check your array count not equal to zero

Answer (score 0):

The size of the array is zero. So, You tried to call `[array objectAtIndex:0]`. 0 is beyond the bounds of an empty array (not surprising – anything is beyond the bounds for an empty array).

Comment: Thnaks for your answer. But I don't understand why the app is crashing because it only happens when using the simulator using iPhone 6 and iPad air. On iPhone 5 everything is perfect. Also this occurs when changing my original bundle ID to a new one I just created. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are u enable In-App Purchase in "App ID"? and also verified that "App ID"  in Provisioning Profile you selected?

Comment: @Thomas Please check this your real device.  Because it happen that some time In-App Purchase not work in simulator. show this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16041136/3378413

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Yes the In-app purchase is enable and provisioning is created. When running on my iPad I have no problem but Apple will reject due to crash.

Comment: Go Window->organizer and select your build which crashed and click on open in project.

Comment: I don't have the option to select open in project - I have upload to app store, validate, export, and download dSYMs.