# How to test apple pay functionality for in-app purchases?

Tags: ios, swift, applepay

I am developing an iOS app with Apple Pay payment facility. I wanna test it. But for the same it is asking to enter a valid card details in wallet. Now I am having doubt while testing the same if it deducts any amount from my card then it would me lossy for me. Can someone guide me for how to test the same?

Suggestions are always welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: i suggest you to use iOS app official help : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ApplePay_Guide/CreateRequest.html

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. :-)

Comment: But I didn't found anything about testing in that documentation. It only specifies how to develop the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using a sandbox tester account, you should check the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html)

[And take a look at this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16040491/how-to-test-iap-in-app-purchase-in-ios-simulator-or-on-the-device)

God speed