# iOS - SKErrorDomain 4

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, swiftystorekit

some new user of our app receiving the error `SKErrorDomain 4` while buying our purchases. I can't reproduce the error and could not find any helpful information in the internet. In apple's forum an user said that the Itunes server were down but that sounds ridiculous. We're using [SwiftyStoreKit](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit) for our IAPs. Here's the code for purchasing a product:

```
            SwiftyStoreKit.purchaseProduct(identifier, atomically: true) { result in

                NetworkActivity.finished()

                if case .success(let purchase) = result {

                    let downloads = purchase.transaction.downloads
                    if !downloads.isEmpty {
                        SwiftyStoreKit.start(downloads)
                    }

                    // Deliver content from server, then:
                    if purchase.needsFinishTransaction {
                        SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(purchase.transaction)
                    }

                }

                switch result {
                case .success(let purchase):
                    observer.send(value: true)
                    observer.sendCompleted()
                case .error(let error):
                    observer.send(error: error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
```

As you can see I return the error with the localized description. We print out our errors in the native alert popup and this is what the user gets (its a german user in our case):

[image: skerrordomain4]

Can someone give me any advice how to proceed here? Also the error is not occuring cause of invalid payment data what I read in another forum. We clarified this with the affected user. He confirmed that everything is correct on his side.

Comment: If you're testing IAPs in a simulator, switch to a physical device: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19126196/3151675

Comment: Yeah I know. The error occurs in production and I can’t reproduce it on a real device. Do you know what the error Stands for?

Comment: According to Apple Developer Documentation, this error occurs when the user is not allowed to authorize payments: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skerror/code/paymentnotallowed

Comment: What does this mean exactly? It’s a rough explanation. Or in other words what should the user do in order to solve this error?

Comment: This normally indicates that in-app purchases are disabled in the restrictions settings

Comment: @StephanHofmann did you ever get this fixed?